# Scala val not accessible outside of if-else

Tags: scala

Why is IntelliJ complaining that it can't resolve symbol 'fields' in the following snippet?

```
  val condition: String = "aa"

  if (condition == "aa") {
    val fields: Int = 2
  } else if (condition == "bb") {
    val fields: Int = 3
  } else if (condition == "cc") {
    val fields: Int = 4
  }

  var g = 1
  while (g < fields) { 
     //do something
     g = g + 1
  }
```

Comment: `val fields: Int = if (condition == "aa") 2 else if (condition == "bb") 3 else 4` or `val fields: Int = condition match { case "aa" => 2; case "bb" => 3; case _ => 4 }`

Comment: Specifying the type as 'Int' in combination with feeding it an if-else structure doesn't work.

Comment: @KoenDeCouck I've just copy-pasted the exact Xavier's code (with if-else) to My Scala 2.12 REPL - it worked perfectly. Match too. And version without types (don't know why you're using those)

Comment: My mistake, it does work with Xavier's code, using 'Int'. I was trying it with other datatypes (i.e. List) and those don't seem to behave different somehow. Still learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of your three variables named `fields` is in Scope on line 12. The scope of a variable starts with its definition and ends when the enclosing block ends.

So the variable `fields` on line 4 is in scope until the `}` on line 5, the one on line 6 until line 7 and the one on line 8 until line 9.

What you want is to define `fields` outside of the `if`s. For that you can use the fact that `if`s are expressions in Scala, so this works:

```
val fields =
  if (condition == "aa") {
    2
  } else ...
```

Comment: Val 'fields' is indeed accessible this way, does this change the type of 'fields' to something other than Int though? I notice that val fields: Int = if ... doesn't work for example ('Expression of type Any does not conform to expected type Int). This causes problems if you later on use methods that specifically require 'Int' type variables.

Comment: @KoenDeCouck The type of `fields` will be the common type of all the branches of the `if`. So if you produce an `Int` in all cases (including the else case), you'll get the type `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

Readability is king:

```
val condition: String = "aa"
val fields = condition match {
    case "aa" => 2
    case "bb" => 3
    case "cc" => 4
}
var g = fields
```

Comment: I also prefer the pattern matching version. May I ask why the enclosing simple brackets around the match in this case?

Comment: No, My answer isn't good, so I will correct this. The answer, however, is, that in different context, namely mapping with a Collection over the switch, I often need brackets to append some ).filter or ).sum or ).mkString in the end. But it doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how it should be, `fields` was not in the scope and also the `if else` expression should make sure to return an `Int`

```
val condition: String = "aa"

val fields: Int = if (condition == "aa") 2
else if (condition == "bb") 3
else if (condition == "cc") 4
else 0 

  var g = 1
  while (g < fields) {
    //do something
    g = g + 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `lexical scoping`.

looking at your code, it might be interesting to know that `if`'s in `scala` are an expression, meaning they have a value.

example:
`val x: Int = if(condition) 4 else 5`